Deploying azure devops pipeline for capacitor iOS mobile ap
I'm trying to create a pipeline on Azure devOps to publish an iOS app (built with capacitor/quasar framework) to the appstore using this yaml file
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: Configuration based on env
  type: string
  default: DEV
  values:
  - PROD
  - DEV
stages:
- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    pool:
      vmImage: macOS-12
    strategy:
      maxParallel: 1
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: install node version
      inputs:
        versionSource: 'spec'
        versionSpec: '16.0.0'
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: install dependencies
      inputs:
        script: |
          npm i -g @quasar/cli
          npm install
          cd src-capacitor
          npm install
    - task: CocoaPods@0
      displayName: install cocoapods
      inputs:
        workingDirectory: 'src-capacitor/ios/App'
        forceRepoUpdate: false
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: npm build
      inputs:
        script: 'quasar build -m capacitor -T ios --skip-pkg'
    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
      displayName: install apple signing certificate
      inputs:
        certSecureFile: 'devTest.p12'
        certPwd: '0000'
        keychain: 'temp'
    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
      displayName: install apple provisioning profile
      inputs:
        provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
        provProfileSecureFile: 'testDev.mobileprovision'
    - task: Xcode@5
      displayName: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis" for "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks"
      inputs:
        buildAction: 'modify'
        xcodeProjPath: 'src-capacitor/ios/App.xcodeproj'
        buildSettings: |
          "TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY[$(Default Platforms)]"="iphoneos"
          "buildSettings[$(SCHEME_NAME)][ENABLE_BITCODE]"="NO"
          "buildSettings[$(SCHEME_NAME)][SWIFT_VERSION]"="5.0"  # Example settings, adjust as needed
          # Add a setting to disable dependency analysis for the script phase:
          "buildSettings[\"Embed Pods Frameworks\"][BASED_ON_DEPENDENCY_ANALYSIS]"="NO"
        sdk: 'iphoneos'
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: 'Ensure proper integration of Capacitor modules'
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo "Ensuring proper integration of Capacitor modules..."
          cd src-capacitor/ios/App  # Navigate to the iOS project directory
          pod install  # Install CocoaPods dependencies
          npx cap sync ios  # Sync Capacitor iOS configuration and dependencies
    - task: Xcode@5
      displayName: 'Building IPA File'
      inputs:
        actions: 'build archive'
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: Naming ipa file
      inputs:
        script: >
          appversion=$(cat package.json | head | grep -w "version" | awk '{print $2}' |cut -c 2-6)

          mv /Users/runner/work/1/s/output/App.ipa /Users/runner/work/1/s/output/myapp_DEV_${appversion}.ipa
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/output'
        Contents: '*.ipa'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'ios'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

However the pipeline fails at building IPA file :

BUILD FAILED **
Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

Problem is xcode is not returning any other errors.

You can try to enable debugging logs to get more detailed logs by set the pipeline variable 'System.Debug' to 'true'. In addition, do you get errors when you try to run xcode build and 'xcode archive' for the same project from your local machine?

From the YAML you provided, I noticed that you are using the default configurations that nosign (Do not code sign) as the signingOption (Signing style) on the Xcode@5 task.
To build and archive IPA file, you need to provide the following signing certificates on the Xcode@5 task.

signingIdentity (Signing identity): It is installed/generated by the InstallAppleCertificate@2 task (Install Apple Certificate). This task will automatically set the variable "APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY" for use.

provisioningProfileUuid (Provisioning profile UUID): It is installed/generated by the InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1 task (Install Apple Provisioning Profile). This task will automatically set the variable "APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID" for use.


Then on the Xcode@5 task, you can configure like as below:
steps:
. . .

- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Building IPA File'
  inputs:
    actions: 'build archive'
    signingOption: manual
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'

For more details, you can reference "Sign your Apple iOS, macOS, tvOS, or watchOS app".

@ardfreak, As suggested above, you need to provide the signing certificates signingIdentity and provisioningProfileUuid on the Xcode@5 task.
